# How many subsequences are there for a permutation of these letters?

Tags: combinatorics

On an exam of mine, we had the following question:

> A subsequence is a sequence that can be derived from another sequence by deleting some elements without changing the order of the remaining elements. For example, the sequence $<A, B, D>$ is a subsequence of $<A, B, C, D, E, F>$ obtained after removal of elements E, C and F.
>
> Assume that each permutation of the letters A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H defines a sequence. How many of these sequences contain the subsequences of $<C, A, B>$ or $<B, E, D>$?

And here's my solution:

> First, it's important to note that they can contain both, like so:
> CABED, so we'll need to apply inclusion-exclusion.
>
> We consider how many ways we can permute with the chunks "CAB" / "BED"
> and the other letters.
>
> CAB + D, E, F, G, H: 6 units to permute = 6!
>
> BED + A, C, F, G, H: 6 units to permute = 6!
>
> CABED + F, G, H: 4 units to permute = 4!
>
> By inclusion-exclusion, there are this many sequences with "CAB" or
> "BED" as substrings:
>
> Answer = 6! + 6! - 4! = 1416

I lost a few points on this, but the professor didn't yet clarify why. Could someone please help me understand what I did wrong? I retraced my steps and couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Also, apologies in advance to anyone who answers if I don't accept your answer today. Gonna go to sleep in a while, but I'll be sure to check back tomorrow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You counted only strings where "CAB" or "BED" appear contiguously. But the definition allows letters to be placed in between. For example "CDEFABGH" contains "CAB" as a substring but 'C' isn't next to 'A'.

Comment: Oh, I see what they were saying now. How would one calculate the number of such subsequences?

Comment: @AleksandrH Think stars and bars.